# Clean Overlapping rectangles in Text Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am performing Word level Text detection on a single page of a book (using [DocTR](https://mindee.com/product/doctr) Model in Python).
I am getting pretty good results (see attached image)

[image]

But the word Bounding boxes are overlapped in some cases, for e.g. **bbox number 45, 46, 47** are overlapping with their neighbours (both in X and Y Axis).

Is there a **simple** (using old school image processing such as opencv) solution to **clean** the rectangles and make it so that each rectangle only envelopes the word itself and not the neighbouring rectangles/words?

PS: The image is always in JPG format. and rectangles are stored in the (X, Y, Width, Height) format.

Comment: You need to show your code as a minimal reproducible example so that others can run it with your original input image and try to fix your code or point out how to fix it.  Also what debugging have you done to isolate where the issue is?  Have you looked at your intermediate images to see if you can track down where it arises.